# CodeIgniter Jquery success give me all page html

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

When I try to send data through ajax jquery in the success i get the whole page html . Other functions work here is my code .

```
                                    <form id ="" action ="" method ="POST">
                                    <?php
                                        $counter = 0 ;
                                        foreach ($all_users as $user) {
                                    ?>
                                    <tr class="">
                                        <td><?php echo $user->user_name; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $user->level ;?></td>
                                        <td>asd</td>
                                        <td><a class="edit" href="javascript:;">Edit</a></td>
                                        <td><a class="delete" onclick ="delete_user($(this),<?php echo $user->id;?>)">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $counter ++;
    }
        ?>
</form>
```

javascript

```
    function delete_user(row_id,user_id)
    {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to delete')) {

            row_id.closest('tr').remove();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete_user/",
                data: { "user_id":user_id },

                success: function(msg) {


                        //alert("Name = " + msg);
                }
            });
        } 
        else {
        // Do nothing!
        }
    }
```

in CI

```
function delete_user()
{
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
    $this->load->model("m_user");
    $this->m_user->delete_user($user_id);
    echo $result;
    echo $user_id;
}
```

I can see that it send the post and data is sent too but i dont get the reply what i get the whole html page code .

Comment: its on live or localhost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same situation i have faced in my project the simple solution for problem is that when you sent request to **`delete_user()`** after this function `codeigniter` calls other functions too you need to stop execution after `delete_user()` executes like using `die()` call

```
function delete_user()
{
$user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');
$this->load->model("m_user");
$this->m_user->delete_user($user_id);
echo $result;
echo $user_id;
die();
}
```

Also in your `JS` code you haven't provide the controller name of the delete function

```
  function delete_user(row_id,user_id)
{
    if (confirm('Do you really want to delete')) {

        row_id.closest('tr').remove();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>/controller_name_required/delete_user/",
            data: { "user_id":user_id },

            success: function(msg) {


                    //alert("Name = " + msg);
            }
        });
    } 
    else {
    // Do nothing!
    }
}
```

hope this helps you

Comment: :D i found that too but thanks alot for the post yes thats the problem , but can u tell me a way that i dont have to write the whole path as i have to move the files to the server too

Comment: ok i have edited again my code see the url part in ajax call controller name is mandatory while you can use CI's base_url() function :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $this->m_user->delete($user_id);
```

Instead

```
   $this->m_user->delete_user($user_id);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but still i get the whole html page . i change the function name so model and controller has unique function name

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out one thing is that

My url is this

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/user/all/
```

Here user is a controller and all is function .

when i try to send data to the function name delete_user may be CI consider it like this

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/user/all/delete_user/
```

I hardcode the url like this

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/user/delete_user/
```

and it shows me that , now can anyone tell me how to solve that url thing ? sorry i am new to CI .

Comment: for more help see this http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html